# List directories, then files - with single command?

Tags: linux, shell-script, ls

I really don't like how Linux `ls -al` mixes files and directories.

Is it possible to list directories, **then** files, with single command?

```
dirA
dirB
dirC
fileA
fileB
fileC
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As usual, `man ls` is your friend. If you're running Linux with the GNU coreutils, the `--group-directories-first` does precisely what you ask for.

Comment: That easy?? I remember it was some pretty complicated script few years back, so I didn't even bother. Maybe I confused it with something else, sorry. Thanks.

Comment: @Danijel well 10 years ago, the option didn't exist :) But it's been present for more than 5 years.

Comment: Well... maybe it was 10 years ago. Time flies... :-)

Comment: For those who didn't catch the subtlety, this will NOT work for `ls` on your mac, which will need those scripts. Mac is BSD and unix-like but not using GNU tool (I understand many expect these low-level tips to be portable, as they often are)